# return multi dimension array to excel from c++ xll

Tags: c++, arrays, export-to-excel, xll

This works fine when i try to pass a 1 dimension array

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER TestArray()
{
    XLOPER xlValues[2];
    xlValues[0].xltype = xltypeNum;
    xlValues[1].xltype = xltypeNum;
    xlValues[0].val.num = 123;
    xlValues[1].val.num = 345;

    static XLOPER xlArray;
    xlArray.xltype = xltypeMulti | xlbitDLLFree;
    xlArray.val.array.rows = 2;
    xlArray.val.array.columns = 1;
    xlArray.val.array.lparray = &xlValues[0];
    return (LPXLOPER)&xlArray;
}
```

But when i try to pass a multi dimension array, the function returns #NUM!

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER TestArray1()
{
    XLOPER xlValues[2][2];
    xlValues[0][0].xltype = xltypeNum;
    xlValues[0][1].xltype = xltypeNum;
    xlValues[1][0].xltype = xltypeNum;
    xlValues[1][1].xltype = xltypeNum;

    xlValues[0][0].val.num = 123;
    xlValues[0][1].val.num = 456;
    xlValues[1][0].val.num = 345;
    xlValues[1][1].val.num = 43456;

    static XLOPER xlArray;
    xlArray.xltype = xltypeMulti | xlbitDLLFree;
    xlArray.val.array.rows = 2;
    xlArray.val.array.columns = 2;
    xlArray.val.array.lparray = &xlValues[0][0];
    return (LPXLOPER)&xlArray;
}
```

Any ideas? thanks in advance!!

Comment: Proof-reading fail: the two pieces of code are identical.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Edited just now :)

Comment: You're not passing a two-dimensional array; you're passing a `XLOPER(*)[2]`. Read the documentation to find out how this differs from what is allowed. Then you will have your answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can you please tell me where can i find this documentation? because i can not find anything.

Comment: You're using a piece of technology without a copy of the documentation? o.O

Comment: @siwmas Did you finally managed to pass two-dimensional arrays ?

Comment: see my answer here  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43392716/3205529

Answer (score 1):

In both TestArray( ) and TestArray1( ) xlValues is a local variable on the stack, so it will be freed by the runtime when the function returns. You need to make xlValues heap allocated memory for this to work reliably. XLL development is something of a dark art. If you're going to get serious about it you should invest in a copy of Steve Dalton's book.