# Return two dimensional array to excel from a c++ xll, the come back

Tags: c++, arrays, excel, xll

First of all I know that the question was already asked here :

[return multi dimension array to excel from c++ xll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533839/return-multi-dimension-array-to-excel-from-c-xll)

I have tried to revive the subject, without success. (The OP not being that active lately, never was.) That's why I am asking the question again, sorry in advance.

I coded up a function returning a (row) one dimensional array :

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12 WINAPI Get1DArray(void)
{
    static XLOPER12 xlArray;
    XLOPER12 xlValues[2];
    xlValues[0].xltype = xltypeNum;
    xlValues[1].xltype = xltypeNum;
    xlValues[0].val.num = 123;
    xlValues[1].val.num = 456;
    xlArray.xltype = xltypeMulti | xlbitDLLFree;
    xlArray.val.array.rows = 1;
    xlArray.val.array.columns = 2;
    xlArray.val.array.lparray = &xlValues[0];
    return static_cast<LPXLOPER12>(&xlArray);
}
```

that works. I tried the same wrong thing the OP from question I was mentionning above tried (that's how I came across the question of his).

The only doc I have is the msdn for excel sdk, it did not help me. The function I coded, I used an example found on the web. Did not find any for two-dimensional array. I know Steve Dalton's books about xll, did not help.

I suspect multidimensional `XLOPER12` arrays stock values in one-dimensional arrays, numbering by rows and columns or columns and rows, but did not succeed in exploiting this intuition...

That's why I am here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example returning a 5*5 matrix. Don't forget to free the allocated array via the `xlAutoFree12` function.

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12 WINAPI Get2DArray(void)
{   
    static XLOPER12 xlArray;
    int rows = 5;
    int cols = 5;
    xlArray.xltype = xltypeMulti | xlbitDLLFree;
    xlArray.val.array.rows = rows;
    xlArray.val.array.columns = cols;
    xlArray.val.array.lparray = reinterpret_cast<LPXLOPER12>(::malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(XLOPER12)));
    for (int r=0;r<rows;r++)
    {
            for (int c=0;c<cols;c++)
            {
                XLOPER12* var = xlArray.val.array.lparray + ((r* cols) + c);
                var->xltype = xltypeNum;
                var->val.num = r*c;
            }
    }
    return &xlArray;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by freeing the allocated array via the `xlAutoFree12` function ? ...

Comment: `val.array.lparray`  is heap allocated (we use malloc)  so you must free it with `::free(reinterpret_cast<void*>(val.array.lparray));` inside the `xlAutoFree12` , cf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687922(v=office.15).aspx. Excel will copy the content of the array and returns the array to the dll via `xlAutoFree12` in order that the dll can free the portion of the heap that has been allocated by the dll and that Excel can't free. To know more about it read the chapter about memory management in Dalton's book.

Comment: Ok, thx. Last point, why the `reinterpret_cast` ? Why the `static_cast` return ?

Comment: `malloc` returns a `void` pointer so you need to reinterpret it to be able to store it in `lparray`. For the `static_cast` , sorry it is a mistake I just removed it.

Comment: Ah ok , thx ! Last point : would I code up a function taking a matrix, modyfing it and returning it, would the type of the parameter of the function still be an `LPXLOPER12 ` ?

Comment: Yes, the LPXLOPER12  can returns any variable (matrix, string, num ...)

Comment: This I understood, my question is about having a parameter that is a matrix

Comment: Yes the same for input variables.

Comment: I tried a `arrayin->val.array.lparray + ((r* cols) + c))->xltype == xltypeNum` where `LPXLOPER12 arrayin` is my input parameter and had a crash. I am taking a 5*5 matrix from excel, at debug I see it having 19 rows and 20 colums, wth !? Is it maybe because when I receive the `LPXLOPER12 arrayin` it represents a range, way more complicated than a 5*5 matrix. How to access the 5*5 matrix it contains, then ?

Comment: If you have another question post it. It will help others users, comments are not for extended discussions and I believe I have answered to your original question.

Comment: And increment your answers counter, but ok, it's best practice indeed ;-)

Comment: Here you go : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397349/receive-a-matrix-from-excel-in-c-xll-modifying-it-and-returning-it